# Difference Ctrl + Shift + T and devtools::test()

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, testthat

What is the differende between the two commands? From RStudio docs it says
[image]

Thus the two should be identical. However, when I run the following test

```
testthat::test_that("create_initial_tourplan works", {
  vrp <- package1::createdata()
  dist_mat <- package::calculate_dist_mat(vrp$locations)
  package2::function2(vrp$locations)
})
```

there are options

1. Run test line by line => OK
2. Ctrl + Shift + T => error: 'vrp' not found
3. devtools::test() => OK

Does anybody have an idea?
Obviously, it is not reproducible, so I can't provide more information (except somebody has an idea what I should provide)

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to come up with a reproducible example if you want any help.

Comment: @user2554330 If you have a look at options 1. and 3. it is definitely not clear how to get a reproducible example except you have an idea what could be going on.

Comment: Just put code in your test that anyone can run.  It's your job to find code that still illustrates the problem; then other people will try it, and help to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference can be explained if you look into the settings of the package (**Build > Configure Build Tools...**):

If the option **Use devtools package functions if available** is NOT checked

- CTRL + SHIFT + T will execute the R files in the *tests* subfolder of the package (where you normally have one R file that calls testthat via `test_check("your_package_name")`),
- otherwise `devtools:test()` is used which directly calls the tests in the *tests/testthat* subfolder.

[image: use devtools package functions if available]

PS: I cannot diagnose what exactly is causing your error message

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the box was checked. It seems, the error disappeared but it is unclear why...